# How to cancel async task when doInBackground is calling another method of separate class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am calling another class's method from doInBackground of async task.
Now i need to stop the download when cancel is called. I am not sure where to check the value of isCancelled().

```
class myasync extends Asynctask{
    protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
        abc = new abc();
        abc.getURLResult(sURL[0])
    }
}

class abc()
{    
    getURLResult(String URL)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<fp.size(); i++){
            //some text to download
        }
    }
}

class myclass
{
    myclass()
    {
        myasync = new myasync();
        myasync.execute("http:\\");
    }

    stopDownload()
    {
        myasync.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Have used the below solution by combining the two answers below:

```
1. myclass.cancel1(true);

 class myclass
    {
        myclass()
        {
            myasync = new myasync();
            myasync.execute("http:\\");
        }

        stopDownload()
        {
            myasync.cancel1(true);
        }
    }

  2. 
 class myasync extends Asynctask{
        protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
            abc = new abc();
            abc.getURLResult(sURL[0])
        }

        cancel1()
        {
         abc.cancel();
         }
    }


3. 
       class abc()
    {    
        private boolean cancel = false;
        getURLResult(String URL)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<fp.size(); i++){
                //some text to download
                 if(cancel)
                    break;
            }
        }

             cancel()
             {
               cancel = true;
              }
    }
```

The above method is working. However the methods `myclass.stopDownload()` is running in UI thread , and hence `myasync.cancel1()` and `abc.cancel()` are running the UI thread. And `myAsync.doInBackground()` and hence `abc.getURLResult()` are running in seperate thread. I dont know much about inter process communication. I hope this is right thing to do.

Comment: have you tried setting the myasync object to null when cancel is clicked. garbage collector should take care of the rest. Havn't tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very nice, but you can do something like this by adding a static variable `isDownloading`:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
abc = new abc();
abc.getURLResult(sURL[0])
}
}

class abc()
{

getURLResult(String URL)
{

 for(int i=0; i<fp.size(); i++){
     if(!myclass.isDownloading){ //ADDED
         break; // or Return or handle Cancel
     }
//some text to dopwnload
}

}

class myclass
{

public static boolean isDownloading; // ADDED

myclass()
{
myasync = new myasync();
isDownloading = true; // ADDED
myasync.execute("http:\\");
}
   stopDownload()
   {
    isDownloading = false; // ADDED
    myclass.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no immediate call back also when cancel() is invoked, else could have set the static variable in that callback, or could have called some method from abc and set some abc variable in that.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

From the AsyncTask Cancel [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)). we have to check if the async task got cancelled as you say.

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this
>   method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. After
>   invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.

To do that send the asyncTask itself to the getURLResult as parameter along with the URL:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
    new abc().getURLResult("http://...", this); // this here is the asyncTask itself.
}

getURLResult(String URL, myasync myAsyncTask)
{
    for(int i=0; i<fp.size(); i++){
        if(myAsyncTask.isCancelled()){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't use a boolean as other suggested. it's not safe at all since another AsyncTask could be started. and it is a background threads. you can't guarantee which will check the boolean first. could cancel all AsyncTasks.

**Old post:**

The only place you need to check for cancellation to guarantee the cancellation! is on the `onPostExecute`. You can't guarantee that the async task got cancelled on calling `cancel` method. Therefore, you need to check whether the client application asked to cancel it and the returned data is not wanted anymore.

```
private boolean askedForCancellation = true;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object response) {
    if (!askedForCancellation)
       // parse response
    else
       // ignore. or send message to activity to stop loading if you didn't already did that when called cancel method.
}
```

To achieve that add the following cancel method to the **AsyncTask**:

```
public final boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    askedForCancellation = true;
    return mFuture.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
}
```

In your class:

```
myasync.cancel(true);
myasync = null;
```

Set myasync to null is ok. because, you can't use it anymore for execution again. you will get a runtime error. you need to re-initialise it.

> To check if AsyncTask asked for cancellation. check if the value of
>   myasync is equal to null. remember the AsyncTask asked to get
>   cancelled and not cancelled because there is no guarantee that it is
>   going to be cancelled on calling cancel. What you do is to ignore the
>   response on `onPostExecute`

I used this approach in more than 15 applications till now. No bugs and no unexpected behaviours.

Comment: I need to come out of the for loop. I need to interrupt the download and stop it.  Onpostexecute () will be called after the completion. If cancel(true ) is invoked, onCancelled () will be executed instead of Onpostexecute(). Though it is a good way to decide whether to send response to client.

Comment: You got this wrong. and your question is wrong. you must say finish download. or stop download. cancelling the async by calling cancel method means that I don't need data and connection anymore get rid of it. don't use cancel. just break the loop it's test anyway. just break after 10 iterations!

Comment: Yes, if i Call cancel(true), the for loop should break and data connection should be disconnected. Once the For loop breaks, DoInBackground will be completed and OnCancelled. I need to call isCancelled() somewhere to break out of loop. Dont know where to call it.

Comment: When i wrote the method 'public final boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)' in aysnc class, I got error 'Cannot override the final method from AsyncTask<String,String,Object>'. Can I call some other method 'myasyc.cancel1()' which will call 'abc.cancel1' But that will be called in ui thread. and doInBackground is runnng in seperate thread.

Comment: What exactly the abc class. Is it going to be existed in a real application?

Comment: https://github.com/hasanalbukhari/Android-Json-Parse-and-Structure/blob/master/src/com/example/parselongjson/HttpClientThread.java use this custom asynctask

Comment: abc is the class which is actually doing the file download. It creates http connection and opens the stream.

Comment: then the for loop there is a test. and you shouldn't any way stop download from there. if user want to stop, it should be from the activity. otherwise it shouldn't be canceled. if that for test reasons create a cancel button and cancel from your activity class. if download goes well or wrong the cancel want happen. don't use cancel in the abc class! just iterate 10 times or so. for (int i=0;i<10;i++) to exactly match the real behaviour of the download. not cancel!

Comment: If the user presses cancel in the activity. The 10 loops should not continue. Lets stop the for loop there and then.

Comment: if user press cancel that mean he is no longer needs the data. let the loop continue since it is a test and the onPostExecute will not be called since the Async got cancelled. in some cases cancel wouldn't happen that's why we check in onPostExecute if the AsyncTask asked to get cancelled. In a real application you will never need an access to the asyncTask in your httpConnection class(abc class). so don't waste your time implementing a structure that will be removed when you go for real application.